# Short version: css top class with different child classes

Tags: css

Is there any short version for following:

```
.ui-content > .ui-grid-solo, .ui-content > .ui-grid-a, .ui-content > .ui-grid-b 
    /* do stuff */ 
}
```

maybe something like:

```
.ui-content > (ui-grid-solo, ui.grid-a, ui-grid-b) {
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, however there is an experimental [`:any()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any) that is in progress to be standardized in the [CSS4 Selector specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches).

The usage would mimic the example you provided:

```
.ui-content > :any(.ui-grid-solo, .ui.grid-a, .ui-grid-b) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Here is a basic example that uses the `:-webkit-any` prefixed version. It works in Chrome:

```css
.ui-content > :-webkit-any(.ui-grid-solo, .ui.grid-a, .ui-grid-b) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-content">
  <p class="ui-grid-solo">Selected.</p>
  <p>Not selected.</p>
</div>
```

---

Aside from adding a common class to all of the desired elements, the best alternative would be to use a CSS preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

In doing so, you can [utilize nesting](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules):

```
.ui-content {
  > .ui-grid-solo,
  > .ui-grid-a,
  > .ui-grid-b { 
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Output:

```
.ui-content > .ui-grid-solo,
.ui-content > .ui-grid-a,
.ui-content > .ui-grid-b {
  /* ... */
}
```

---

As a side note, this probably isn't what you're looking for, but it's worth pointing out that you could always use the universal selector in order to target all direct children elements:

```
.ui-content > * {
  /* ... */
}
```

You could even negated elements as well:

```
.ui-content > *:not(.ignore-me) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I choose this one as accepted answer because it also gives a nice view to css4.

Answer (score 1):

There is no grouping mechanism like that in CSS. You can give `.ui-grid-solo`, `.ui-grid-a`, and `.ui-grid-b` a common class, say `.ui-grids`, then target `.ui-content > .ui-grids`